# Configuration in Java Play - ebean and postgresql

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I can't make my Play Framework project run properly. I want to use a postgresql db and ebean, but there's something wrong with the configuration and I keep getting compilation errors. Could you have a look and check what might be the reason?

My build.sbt file:

```
import play.sbt.PlayJava

name := """play-java-intro"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42",
  "javax.persistence" % "persistence-api" % "1.0.2"
)

fork in run := true
```

plugins.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.13")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

My model class:

```
package models;
import java.util.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Finder;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String surname;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date date;

    public static Finder<Long,Person> finder = new Finder<Long, Person>(Person.class);
}
```

And the error message:

```
[error] com.avaje.ebean.Finder
[error] /home/guras/play-java-intro/app/models/Person.java:6: package com.avaje.ebean does not exist
[error] /home/guras/play-java-intro/app/models/Person.java:7: package com.avaje.ebean does not exist
[error] com.avaje.ebean.Model
[error] /home/guras/play-java-intro/app/models/Person.java:15: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol: class Model
[error] Model
[error] /home/guras/play-java-intro/app/models/Person.java:28: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class Finder
[error]   location: class models.Person
[error] Finder
[error] /home/guras/play-java-intro/app/models/Person.java:28: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class Finder
[error]   location: class models.Person
[error] Finder


[info] play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$playExceptionPickler$$anon$1: Compilation error[package com.avaje.ebean does not exist]
[info]  at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$playExceptionPickler$.unpickle(Serializers.scala:159)
[info]  at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$PlayRunsupportReloaderCompileFailureUnpickler$macro$56$2$.unpickle(Serializers.scala:175)
[info]  at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$PlayRunsupportReloaderCompileResultUnpickler$macro$66$2$.unpickle(Serializers.scala:181)
[info]  at scala.pickling.Unpickler$class.unpickleEntry(Pickler.scala:79)
[info]  at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$PlayRunsupportReloaderCompileResultUnpickler$macro$66$2$.unpickleEntry(Serializers.scala:181)
[info]  at scala.pickling.functions$.unpickle(functions.scala:11)
[info]  at sbt.serialization.JsonValue$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(SerializedValue.scala:104)
[info]  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
[info]  at sbt.serialization.JsonValue.parse(SerializedValue.scala:104)
[info]  at sbt.protocol.BuildValue.value(Values.scala:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ebean jars into your class path as dependency. The imports are failing because  You don't have the dependency jars containing those packages in your class path.
You can find the jars in Maven centeral repository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.avaje/ebean)

Comment: Now I've got "addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.8.1")"  in plugins.sbt, and  "org.avaje" % "ebean" % "2.8.1" in build.sbt, but Intellij can't resolve it. Do you have any other idea? It seems that those libraries are not downloaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

On you plugins.sbt

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.1.0")`

On your build.sbt 
`lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaCore,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1212"
)
```

You have to enable ebean plugin in order to work with play framework.